# Deploying a flow file remotely in node-red without overwriting the entire flow file

Tags: node-red

I want to import a json file into node-red dynamically instead of doing it manually, and I tried to use curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:1880/flows -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "@myflow.json"
```

I successfully saw the new flow inside but it overwrote all my previous flows, also the /data/flows.json has been overwritten, however, I would like to add the new flow after the previous one, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The Node-RED AdminAPI is documented [here](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/).

> **GET**     `/flows`      Get the active flow configuration
>
> **POST**    `/flows`      Set the active flow configuration
>
> **POST**    `/flow`       Add a flow to the active configuration
>
> **GET**     `/flow/:id`   Get an individual flow configuration
>
> **PUT**     `/flow/:id`   Update an individual flow configuration
>
> **DELETE**  `/flow/:id`   Delete an individual flow configuration

The one you are looking for is [**POST** `/flow`](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/flow/)

Note there is no `s` on the end and be sure to check the doc to see if the JSON payload matches what you have (as it is slightly different than a complete flow file as found in the userDir)